# Hadoop Map Reduce CustomRecordReader Reduce Phase

Tags: java, hadoop

i am new to hadoop. I successfully created a custom RecordReader and a custom type called "Allineamento" so:

```
public class Allineamento extends Object implements WritableComparable<Allineamento>
```

the map phase works and finishes his jobs. When the reduce phase starts i have this [exception](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/8386/ntto.png):

Someone suggests me to insert in "Allineamento" an empty constructor (public Allineamento(){}). Is this the way? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the empty constructor, apparently Hadoop needs the class to have a default constructor, so just add it.

```
public class Allineamento {
    public Allineamento() {

    }
}
```

And it should work.